# Image inside a View element is not aligning to the right in React Native

Tags: css, react-native

I am implementing a tile in reactnative and I have to make the Image right in the tile just like this
[What I want (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L212C.png)

and this is what I can implement till now
[What I get ()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W577E.png)

this is my code

```
<View style={styles.container} >
      <Image
        style={styles.image}
        source={item.image}
        resizeMode="cover"
      />
      <View style={styles.overlay} />
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.subText}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.headingText}>{item.message}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
```

and this is style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#206c72',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    borderRadius: 15,
    width: COURSE_ITEM_WIDTH,
    elevation: 7,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
    marginTop: 20
  },
  image: {
    width: COURSE_ITEM_WIDTH,
    height: 120,
    borderRadius: 10
  },
  textContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 16,
    flex: 1,
  },
  headingText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#ffffff',
    marginTop: 5
  },
  subText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
  timeText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 5
  },
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#206c72',
    opacity: 0.6,
    borderRadius: 10
  }
})
```

Please help me i dont know what i am doing wrong. thanks in advance!

> [note: please ignore the content, focus on alignment]

Answer (score 0):

Your image is aligned to the right but there is nothing at the left of it. You should add `flexDirection:'row'` to the parent container and put an empty View with `width : 40px` before your image.
You can also remove the `alignItems:flex-end` and `justifyContent:center`  from the main container

Comment: Well this is looking like [this](https://imgur.com/a/lQhW3gn)

Comment: you can add `justifyContent:'space-between'` in the container style and adjust the width value

Comment: sorry but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can add alignSelf property to flex-end for image and image will be on end of the tile.

example 1:

```
 image: {
    width: "50%",
    height: 120,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "red", //for making sure how much space is taken by image you can remove on further
    alignSelf: "flex-end"
  },
```

for reference i tried a sandbox example check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-mirzakhani-rvlp8t?file=/src/App.js:3416-3541)

also noticed you are using alignItems value twice first one is only necessary you can remove 2nd alignItems and position relative value from styles.container then it will align the image to end. you will get the exact result you want

example 2:

```
container: {
    backgroundColor: '#206c72',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',   // only need this alignItems 
    borderRadius: 15,
    width: COURSE_ITEM_WIDTH,
    elevation: 7,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20
  },
image: {
    width: "50%",
    height: 120,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "red", //for making sure how much space is taken by image you can remove on further
    // no need of alignSelf to flex-end here
  },
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but in my case [this is what it is looking like](https://imgur.com/a/SC9JgfT) when using your code

Comment: after making container width 100% [this is what i am getting](https://imgur.com/ajpO3S1)

Comment: Its working fine on that code sandbox. I think you are using same width for container and image `width: COURSE_ITEM_WIDTH,`  for the container and use `width: '50%'` on your image. I can't  reproduce that issue on my code sandbox.

Comment: Also can you try `resizeMode="stretch"`